# importing from phone contacts to my application in iphone

Tags: iphone

i want implement an application such a way that to import all contacts from the device and to display in a tableview in my application is possible to do that ...

if possible can any one tell me how to do that....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope this will be useful. I made that for you http://www.jorgedelprado.com.ar/ABExample.zip

Comment: of course this on is very helpful to me. is it possible if i made any changes in my tableview that my reflect to the phone contacts when i run the application in iphone.(what i mean is if i add a contact in the tableview that will directly add to the phone contacts.)

Comment: Sure. You can do that by using the Addressbook framework. Take a look at the docs. I can't spend more time writing examples. There are a lot of sample code out of there. Also use google, it's very helpful for me... http://www.google.com.ar/#hl=es-419&biw=1111&bih=544&q=add+a+contact+to+addressbook+iphone+sdk&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&fp=c08b28ce5c271bb1

Comment: This one is fine but I want to add only selected contacts to my application from the address book how to do that. By clicking the appropriate cell in the phone address book I want to add that particular contact to my application contact . Can you tell me how to do that..

Comment: The link is dead, that makes the answer not very useful.