# Get Iphone phonebook contacts

Tags: iphone, sqlite, contacts

How to import all my iphone phonebook contacts into my app tableview or in sqlite ?

Comment: You need to write the code in objective-c using the Address book framework. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/QuickStart.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH2-SW1

Comment: Helps to search first before asking another SO question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859418/importing-from-phone-contacts-to-my-application-in-iphone.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
NSArray *contacts = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
```

Your have then NSArray of contacts which you use to fill your tableview.

Comment: is there any framework tat i have to add in my project ? because its showing error msg  "_ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople", referenced from: in someviewcontroller.o

Comment: as Praveen S has suggested, you should have a look at the standard Apple address book framework.

Comment: @Karthik - you need to `#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>`, and add the Address Book framework to your linked library list.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a [standard framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/AddressBook_iPhoneOS_Framework/_index.html) for doing this. There are some examples of code out there that you can refer too. [Here](http://www.picksourcecode.com/ps/ct/161169.php) is one of them.